# DateTime filter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLETABLE 
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS DATETIME) =  '2020-01-01 09:00:58'
```

which is working for me. but I have input in yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss that is

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLETABLE 
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS DATETIME) =  '2020-01-01 09:00'
```

which returns zero records. How to filter this data?

Comment: Is `CreatedDate` a varchar?

Comment: its datetime...

Comment: You'll want to avoid using a `CAST` on the column then, as you'll force a sequential scan of the entire table rather than using an index.  You'll want `SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2020-01-01 09:00:00' AND '2020-01-01 09:00:59'`

Comment: That would omit the times `2020-01-01 09:00:593` and `2020-01-01 09:00:597` though, @MikeChristensen . You're better off using `>=` and `<` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare `datetime` to `datetime`, the whole value (including the fraction seconds) will be compared. Equality will only give you true when both operands are really equal.

When you compare to a string, SQL Server will try to convert one of the values to the data type of the other value. This is called [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). In case of `datetime` and `varchar`, `varchar` will be converted to `datetime` (when appropriate rule is found to convert the string) due to [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Therefore you cannot say, that any given datetime value is equal to any arbitrary string representing a date and time.

You expect to get all values in the range of `2020-01-01 09:00:00.000` and `2020-01-01 09:00:59.999`, however this is not how date and time works in SQL.

If you can have such inputs, you either have to interpret them and do your search using the intervals you expect, like

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLETABLE 
WHERE CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01 09:00:00.000'
  AND CreatedDate < '2020-01-01 09:01:00.000'
```

Or you can cast your datetime value to the sting format you got:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLETABLE 
WHERE FORMAT(CreatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') =  '2020-01-01 09:00'
```

The second approach is less performant in most RDBMS (SQL Server for sure) due to the conversion (calculation) done on the field itself, which will prevent the database server to use indexes on said column/to aid said filter.

Note, that you don't have to cast/convert your column to `datetime` if it is a `datetime` already.